# Javascript scoping for class properties

Tags: javascript, ajax, class, scope

So, i have this code ( stripped )

```
var Categories;
Categories = {url:'someurl', list : [] };
Categories.CreateCategory = function ()
{
  // do some checks
  // gather some data

$.ajax( {/*ajax options here, expecting JSON format*/} )
.done(function ( data )
  {
      var ctg = new Category();
      ctg.Id = data.id;
      Categories.list[ctg.id] = ctg;
  } )
}
```

However, the new category doesn't get appended to the list.

I tried to

- Change the context of the ajax call to **this** or **Categories**
- Box the Categories variable ( `var s=Categories; ...; s.list[ctg.Id] = ctg; Categories = s; )`
- Create a new method that appends the new category to the list

None of those work.

**Some more info**

The CreateCategory method is intended to be used in the admin panel of a website, that's why i need to extend the Categories class in a separate script.

The previous version which contained the entire version of the Categories class, with a bunch of code identical to the users version, worked like a charm.

---

**Solved**

As it turns out i had a typo in the code.

```
  Categories.list[ctg.id] = ctg;
```

should be

```
  Categories.list[**ctg.Id**] = ctg;
```

Comment: Any errors on the JS console?  Have you tried using a debugger to step through the callback function?

Comment: Are you sure that the done function is even getting called?

Comment: @cdhowie No errors in the console related to that function. console.log(Categories.list) in the done functions shows that the category is added.

Comment: @arriu Yes. Aside from that code, the category is also added to the document. It shows up ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in:

`Categories.list[ctg.id] = ctg;`

`ctg.id` should be `ctg.Id`

Comment: Note that this is still not going to work as expected if `ctg.Id` is non-numeric - it's being added as a property to the array, and if the id is `"foo"` it won't show up as an element in the array.

Comment: This is awkward. 2 hours wasted.

Comment: @your_average_programmer i know that feel bro

Answer (score 1):

put a fail too, if have a error you'll not know, and you can use the `.push` to update the `.length`property

```
var Categories;
Categories = {url:'someurl', list : [] };
Categories.CreateCategory = function ()
{
  // do some checks
  // gather some data

  $.ajax( {/*ajax options here, expecting JSON format*/} )
  .done(function ( data )
  {
      var ctg = new Category();
      ctg.Id = data.id;
      Categories.list.push(ctg);
   } )
   .fail(function(){
     console.log("error on get category");
     console.log(arguments);
   })
}
```

Comment: Works. The downside is that i was keeping the list array to resemble a dictionary, for easy of access. I guess i have to add a method that retrieves the of the category now

Comment: if you want a dictionary you can use a object instead a array... like `Categories.list = {};` and access only by index or you can do a filter proccess to get the item `Categories.get = function(id){ Categories.list.filter(function(cat){ return cat.id == id; })[0]; }` I think will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue here is that `Categories.list` is an array, but you're assigning a property via `Categories.list[ctg.id]`. @tpb rightly notes that you've got a typo there, which might be the source of your problems, but whether or not this will work as expected is going to depend on the value of the `id` property. You almost certainly want to either:

- Use `.push()` to add the new value to the array, or
- Use an object instead of an array for `list`.

To test:

```
var a = [];
a["foo"] = 1; // a now has a property called "foo", but it's not an array member
a; // []
a[10] = 2; // a has 2 at pos 10, which sticks in 10 undefined values
a; // [undefined x 10, 2]
```

So this is only a good idea if you know for a certainty that the set of `id` values is all numeric and is densely sequential.

Comment: The id is always numeric and unique, retrieved from a MySql database where it's set as a primary key.

Comment: Still not a great idea unless it's sequential starting at `0`. Even then, you're usually better off not assuming anything about an id value, as you might need to handle other kinds of ids later.

Comment: I expect about 10-20 array members. I don't want to go overboard optimizing it, for now.

Comment: Not a question of count, but of whether their sequential and start at zero. If not, you might get weird/undesirable results on iteration. For example, `a = []; a[10] = "foo"` leaves `a.length` at `11` even though you only have one member. If you need an array, don't key it to the id; if you need it keyed to the id, use an object.